# Anomaly on sensors! But where is it actually?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Suvi is constantly telling me that there is an anomaly on sensors, but I can't find anything.

[image]

At first I though this obviously means there is something on the planets marked with an exclamation mark in the screenshot above, but I now visited all of them and they were empty.

And Suvi still keeps telling me there is something here. So we're is that anomaly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example, the anomaly is the small bright dot on the right side of the asteroid belt (that also might be a gas belt from the looks of it). Hover your cursor over it and start scanning, and it will pop up an icon just like it does when you scan a planet. Then fire a probe and you can go mine the asteroid, or whatever it turns out to be.

Comment: I didn't notice that you could scan on the solar system view as well, I thought that only worked on planets.

Comment: Should probably note that if you bring up the scanner elsewhere on the screen, there's an arrow telling you which direction to go to find the anomaly.